# select a single dropdown on click and not multiple

Tags: javascript, php

i have multiples cards with masonry, and i have added a dropwdown menu when clicking on a icon.
When i'm clicking on the icon, every cards show the dropdown menu or i want just the one i'm clicking.

HTML :

```
<div class="dropdown">
<i class="fas fa-share-alt-square social-menu"></i>
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com"></i>Facebook</a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com"></i>Facebook</a>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$('.social-menu').click(function() {
    $('.dropdown-content').toggleClass('show');
  });
  $(document).click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('.social-menu').length) {
      if ($('.dropdown-content').is(":visible")) {
        $('.dropdown-content').toggleClass('show');
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: You should use `$(this).closest('.social-menu').length` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need 2 `click` handler to do it.

Only thing you need to keep in mind is that you have to `show` the `dropdown-content` which are really close to `social-menu` being clicked. considering your `HTML` structure you can do it like:

```
$('.social-menu').click(function() {
    var parentDiv = $(this).closest(".dropdown"); //find the parent div holding <i> as well as dropdown-content
    parentDiv.find('.dropdown-content').toggleClass('show'); //target the exact dropdown-content
});
```